# Conditionally disabled select option in React

Tags: reactjs, react-select, select-options

I built my own React select component and would like to have an option to set the default value to be `disabled`

The component basically looks like this:

```
<select
    id={this.props.id}
    name={this.props.name}
    value={this.props.value}
    defaultValue={this.props.default}
    onClick={this.handleFieldClick}
    onChange={this.handleFieldChange} >

         <option value="" disabled={this.defaultDisabled ? true : false} >{this.props.defaultLabel}</option>

         { Object.keys(this.props.options).map((val, i) => ( 
             <option key={i} value={val}>{this.props.options[val]}</option>
         ))}

 </select>
```

This line giving me the issue is the following:

```
<option value="" disabled={this.defaultDisabled ? true : false} >{this.props.defaultLabel}</option>
```

The "disabled" option is still selectable and renders like this:

```
<option value="" selected="">Default Option</option>
```

I believe it's because the correct syntax for a disabled option is `<option disabled ></option>`, not `<option disabled="true" ></option>`

But when I format my JSX as follows:

```
<option value="" {this.defaultDisabled ? "disabled" : ""} >{this.props.defaultLabel}</option>
```

I get an error that crashes the app.

What is the correct syntax for conditionally writing a directive value into a tag with JXS and/or conditionally set a disabled option in React?

Comment: React should handle boolean elements correctly, i.e. `<option disabled={true}>...</option>` should render as `<option disabled>...</option>`, so it should behave as you want. When you say you're getting an issue from that, what issue exactly, and where is that issue coming from?

Comment: the issue is that the `disabled` option is still selectable

Comment: Looking at that again, you have an error in your code: `disabled={this.defaultDisabled ? true : false}` should be `disabled={this.props.defaultDisabled ? true : false}` (you missed a `.props`). Assuming that's coming directly from your code that would explain the issue.

Comment: godammit! you have no idea how many times Ive looked at that code and still missed it. thank you.

Comment: I do know, because we've all done it :D

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You missed a `.props`. And you can also use `null` instead of `false`.

```
<option value="" disabled={this.props.defaultDisabled ? true : null} >{this.props.defaultLabel}</option>
```

Comment: Why `null` and not `false`?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin you can use null, but false works as well

Answer (score 8):

After a couple of time, I finally fixed the issue.

It seems that in React to use `selected` attribute on the HTML tag is not recommended. The best ways to set a default value is to use `defaultValue` If you use it, it will throw an error in development and keep quiet in production.

[More info can be found here](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values)

## How to avoid such error

- Step one

  1. Give default value to HTML `select` Tag

```
     <select
       name="originId"
       defaultValue="Choose-origin"
     >
```

2. Give `option` tag the `value` which is equal to  `defaultValue` of `select`

```
     <option
        value="Choose-origin"     // normally in VanillaJS you would use "selected"
        disabled
     >Choose origin</option>
```

3. Remember to disable the `option` tags so that you deny the user to click it.

Thanks, to @Neo Choi and @Bernard Leech for help.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
    <option 
      value=""
      disabled={this.props.defaultDisabled}
    >
      {this.props.defaultLabel}
    </option>
```