# How to make a disabled option in a select, as a placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-select

I tried the solution below, in theory it works, but react returns this: Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on  instead of setting `selected` on .

```js
<Select>
   <OptionPlaceholder selected disabled>
         Escolha uma opção...
   </OptionPlaceholder>
</Select>
```

The purpose is only to remove this warning, but any other solution that ive tryied dont get me the expecting result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally disabled select option in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164838/conditionally-disabled-select-option-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

you missed a `props`

`<option value="" disabled={this.props.defaultDisabled}>`

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the `value` or `defaultValue` attribute of the `select` in React instead of the `selected` prop of the `option`!

Here is an example with the `value` attribute:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

// ...

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    value: '',
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const { value } = event.target

    this.setState({ value })
  }

  render () {
    const { value } = this.state

    return (
      <Select value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <OptionPlaceholder disabled>
          Escolha uma opção...
        </OptionPlaceholder>
      </Select>
    )
  }
}
```

> Or take a look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag)

Answer (score 0):

It's just the reference code, because you need to add an option as `defaultValue` and handle it during your validation if it is selected or not. Or make use of `onChange` handlers to modify a state variable:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '1'
        };
    }

    render(){
       return(
           <select value={this.state.value} onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({value: e.target.value})}}>
              <option value='1' disabled>Select</option>
              {
                  [2,3,4].map((i,j)=>{
                      return <option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>
                  })
              }
           </select>
       );
    }
}
```